# How can I use multiple entries in Webpack alongside multiple HTML files in HtmlWebpackPlugin?

Tags: javascript, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

We'd like to have two outputs from Webpack - our entire app with all of its dependencies, and a single different page with only one dependency (that isn't shared by the main app).

It seems the way to do this is to leverage the `entry` property of a Webpack config. However, that's not enough, as we also use [HtmlWebpackPlugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin) to output our HTML file with the `build.js` that Webpack compiled dynamically added (as well as compiled LESS, etc). According to the HtmlWebpackPlugin docs:

> If you have multiple Webpack entry points, they will all be included
>   with script tags in the generated HTML.

That won't work for us, so I need to leverage their `filterChunks` option. This [GitHub issue response](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/218#issuecomment-183066602) states it most succinctly:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'page1': './apps/page1/scripts/main.js',
    'page2': './apps/page2/src/main.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: "apps/[name]/build/bundle.js"
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: false,
      chunks: ['page1'],
      filename: 'apps/page1/build/index.html'
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: false,
      chunks: ['page2'],
      filename: 'apps/page2/build/index.html'
    })
  ]
};
```

(in the HtmlWebpackPlugin docs, this is under the "filtering chunks" section)

So, I modified our code like so:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './public/js/ide.js',
        resetPassword: './public/js/reset_password.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../build'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    ...
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'index.html',
            template: 'public/html/ide.html',
            inject: true,
            chunks: ['app']
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'reset_password.html',
            template: 'public/html/reset_password.html',
            inject: true,
            chunks: ['resetPassword']
        }),
    ],
}
```

Now, when I rebuild the project (just trying with WebpackDevServer for now) and navigate to `/index.html`, I can see in the network tab the massive bundle file, the contents of `index.html` (based off the `ide.html` template), as well as requests for various external resources. However, no actual JavaScript will run (say, a console.log in `ide.js`). All the HTML in the file shows.

For `reset_password.html`, all HTML shows, and the `reset_password.js` file shows, but none of the javascript within runs.

How can I ensure the JavaScript in my `entry` files runs?

**EDIT**: I have gotten `ide.js` working, because I hadn't realized the following was a "chunk":

```
optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                commons: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    name: 'vendor',
                    chunks: 'all'
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

So, I added `vendor` to the `index.html` HtmlWebpackPlugin `chunks` property. Now, it looks like this:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    filename: 'index.html',
    template: 'public/html/ide.html',
    inject: true,
    chunks: ['app', 'vendor']
}),
```

`reset_password` doesn't need anything in the node_modules folder, and this also doesn't explain why no JavaScript at all would run inside of `ide.js`, so I'm still quite confused. Also, `reset_password` is still non-functional.

**EDIT2**: Looking through the apparently attached `reset_password.js` file when I load `reset_password.html`, I can see this line

```
eval("\n\nconsole.log('DRAGONHELLO');//# sourceURL=[module]\n//# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64,eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjozLCJzb3VyY2VzIjpbIndlYnBhY2s6Ly8vLi9wdWJsaWMvanMvcmVzZXRfcGFzc3dvcmQuanM/ZjY5ZSJdLCJuYW1lcyI6WyJjb25zb2xlIiwibG9nIl0sIm1hcHBpbmdzIjoiOztBQUNBQSxRQUFRQyxHQUFSLENBQVksYUFBWiIsImZpbGUiOiIuL3B1YmxpYy9qcy9yZXNldF9wYXNzd29yZC5qcy5qcyIsInNvdXJjZXNDb250ZW50IjpbIlxuY29uc29sZS5sb2coJ0RSQUdPTkhFTExPJylcbiJdLCJzb3VyY2VSb290IjoiIn0=\n//# sourceURL=webpack-internal:///./public/js/reset_password.js\n");
```

So, clearly my `console.log('DRAGONHELLO')` is "seen", but I have no idea why it isn't running.

**EDIT3**: Adding `vendor` to `chunks` for `reset_password.html` causes the JavaScript to run, but I have no idea why, and this is non-ideal because the whole point of the exercise was to have two different bundles, one which was very minimal and didn't need all of our `node_modules`.

**EDIT4**: I ran Webpack with `profile:true`, and I can see I'm not getting the "Chunk Names" wrong:

```
                 js/app.3d18b43294ebd54ed083.js   1.34 MiB       0  [emitted]  [big]  app
       js/resetPassword.198485be2b163cc258ed.js   1.02 KiB       1  [emitted]         resetPassword
                   js/2.e7f92193ea3c611a0b36.js   2.23 MiB       2  [emitted]  [big]  vendor
             js/app.3d18b43294ebd54ed083.js.map   2.71 MiB       0  [emitted]         app
   js/resetPassword.198485be2b163cc258ed.js.map   4.57 KiB       1  [emitted]         resetPassword
               js/2.e7f92193ea3c611a0b36.js.map   7.12 MiB       2  [emitted]         vendor
```

**EDIT5**: I tried both

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: {
      name: entrypoint => `runtime~${entrypoint.name}`
    }
  }
};
```

and

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: true
  }
};
```

Based on PlayMa256's comment and the [webpack docs on runtimeChunk](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimization-runtimechunk). Neither caused the JavaScript to execute.

Comment: you need runtimeChunk: true in order to execute the bundles. And that has to be included in both places

Comment: can you clarify? In which both places?

Comment: Please see edit5. Based on what I read up on your suggestion, I tried some minor experimentation, none of which worked. I would be very grateful if you could elucidate where else I should add the runtimeChunk option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a multipart issue.

First, [there is a bug in Html-Webpack-Plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/1053#issuecomment-424298473) that makes it incompatible with Webpack4 and multiple entrypoints. It must be upgraded to [v4.0.0-alpha.2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-plugin/v/4.0.0-alpha.2) at least to work.

Second, in the new version, you needn't use use `optimization.splitChunks.cacheGroups` to manually separate out node_modules. Doing `optimization.splitChunks.chunks = 'all'` is enough to result in a given entrypoint only getting in its `vendors-app-{{chunk_name}}` chunk the node_modules it actually `import`s.

So if you do

```
optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
        chunks: 'all'
    },
},
```

Combined with

```
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: 'index.html',
        template: 'public/html/ide.html',
        inject: true,
        chunks: ['app']
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: 'reset_password.html',
        template: 'public/html/reset_password.html',
        inject: true,
        chunks: ['resetPassword']
    }),
]
```

Combined with

```
entry: {
    app: './public/js/ide.js',
    resetPassword: './public/js/reset_password.js'
},
```

Then, your webpack output will have

1. app
2. resetPassword
3. vendors~app~resetPassword
4. vendors~app
5. vendors~resetPassword

Unless you have no `imports` in your `resetPassword.js` file, in which case it will look like

1. app
2. resetPassword
3. vendors~app~resetPassword (necessary webpack vendor packages)
4. vendors~app

More information, images, and conversation at https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/1053

Note that `chunksSortMode:` is no longer a valid option on the HtmlWebpackPlugin object for the newest version, it is apparently done by default in webpack4.

Comment: This issue i had was with using HtmlWebpackPlugin i could not for the life of me get the code to execute. All imports were correct, but the chunk specificed in the HtmlWebpackPlugin config wouldn't actually run. Tried using runtime flag as well. 

The only solution was to name the splitChunks, which whilst it worked, i felt defeated the point of splitChunks.

Comment: Thanks much for mentioning that the plugin version before V4 had a bug, its 2020 and still the default install had installed V3.2.0 which I had to upgrade.

Answer (score 3):

When you set:

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: true
  }
};
```

It generates a runtime chunk. What is a runtime? Runtime is where ALL the code that webpack uses to load other files are. This is the heart of webpack when you run build.

Since you have 2 separate bundle files: `resetPassword` and `app`.

Ok, you have all the files you need. You maybe need vendors on both too, since vendor in your case contains everything from node_modules. So basically you will have:

html 1: `app`, `vendor`, `runtimeChunk`.

html 2: `reset_password`, `vendor`, `runtimeChunk`.

By doing that, you application should run.

Comment: According to https://gist.github.com/sokra/1522d586b8e5c0f5072d7565c2bee693 , "optimization.runtimeChunk: true adds an additonal chunk to each entrypoint containing only the runtime.". You're saying "runtime" is webpack's code for loading files? Hmm. Adding `runtimeChunk: true` to `optimization` caused both the `app` and `reset_password` to not work

Comment: but did you add runtime to both of htmls? In the top of the file

Comment: Oh, no let me try that

Comment: ```
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'index.html',
            template: 'public/html/ide.html',
            inject: true,
            chunks: ['app', 'vendor', 'runtimeChunk']
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'reset_password.html',
            template: 'public/html/reset_password.html',
            inject: true,
            chunks: ['resetPassword', 'runtimeChunk'],
        }),
```

Comment: Still didn't work. I'm building right now with `profile` enabled, to see what the name of the chunks are. One moment.

Comment: manually add them in order to test, you don't need to bundle them everytime

Comment: You mean put like <script src="runtimeChunk.js"> into the html files?

Comment: Ah, hold on, in the bundle, looks like they're named `runtime~app` and `runtime~reset_password`. And I shouldn't do it manually because I need to deploy this to jenkins and other people's computers, for one thing lol. But I appreciate your help so far, this will likely be the correct answer.

Comment: You don't need to do that manually all the time... do that just for the sake of testing... when you figure out if it works you do that correctly.

Comment: So, manual testing I believe is unecessary. With your recommendation, I added `runtime-app` to and `runtime-~reset_password` to each of the HtmlWebpackPlugin places. Now, `app` works (root url), however, /reset_password.html still does not run javascript. The reason manually testing is unecessary is I can properly see both javascript files injected in the html in the inspector: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/runtime~resetPassword.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/resetPassword.js"></script>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180538/discussion-between-playma256-and-caleb-jay).