# How to separate out webpack-dev-server from my splitChunks in Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, html-webpack-plugin

I am trying to get multiple entrypoints working with webpackDevServer.

One entrypoint requires my entire node_modules folder. The other requires only a single file, with a single console.log in it (the entrypoint file).

For some reason, my single file with a single console.log won't run. [See this question as well.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52434167/how-can-i-use-multiple-entries-in-webpack-alongside-multiple-html-files-in-htmlw)

I was testing this setup in WebpackDevServer, so I suspected that all files needed at least WebpackDevServer to function, maybe. So, I changed my `optimization.splitChunks` to look like this, [based off the example on the webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#split-chunks-example-3):

```
optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
            commons: {
                test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                name: 'vendor',
                chunks: 'all'
            },
            vendor: {
                test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/](webpack|webpack-dev-server)[\\/]/,
                name: 'webpack',
                chunks: 'all',
            }
        }
    },
},
```

I expect there to be a "vendor" bundle and a "webpack" bundle. There is only "vendor" (and my entrypoints):

```
                                         app.js   6.92 MiB            app  [emitted]  app
                               resetPassword.js   35.2 KiB  resetPassword  [emitted]  resetPassword
                                      vendor.js   14.4 MiB         vendor  [emitted]  vendor
```

**How can I get `webpack-dev-server` into its own bundle**, which I can then include into HtmlWebpackPlugin, to test to see if that (or other node_modules) are what's needed to run my `console.log`?

*Webpack config*

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './public/js/ide.js',
        resetPassword: './public/js/reset_password.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../build'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    ...
optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
            commons: {
                test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                name: 'vendor',
                chunks: 'all'
            },
            vendor: {
                test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/](webpack|webpack-dev-server)[\\/]/,
                name: 'webpack',
                chunks: 'all',
            }
        }
    },
},
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'index.html',
            template: 'public/html/ide.html',
            inject: true,
            chunks: ['app', 'vendor']
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'reset_password.html',
            template: 'public/html/reset_password.html',
            inject: true,
            chunks: ['resetPassword'] // this does not work
            //chunks: ['resetPassword', 'vendor'] //this works
        }),
    ],
}
```

*reset_password.js*

```
console.log('hello')
```

*webpack dev server config*

```
devServer: {
    clientLogLevel: 'warning',
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: true,
    compress: true,
    host: HOST,
    port: PORT,
    open: config.dev.autoOpenBrowser,
    overlay: false,
    publicPath: '/',
    contentBase: [
        path.join(__dirname, "../../public"), 
        path.join(__dirname, "../../public/js")],
    watchOptions: {
        poll: config.dev.poll,
    },
    disableHostCheck: true,
    https: true,
    noInfo: false,
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a priority attribute to each of the chunks. From the [docs](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/).

> **splitChunks.cacheGroups.priority**
>
> number
>
> A module can belong to multiple cache groups. The optimization will prefer the cache group with a higher priority. The default groups have a negative priority to allow custom groups to take higher priority (default value is 0 for custom groups).

So your code would be something like this. Note that the priority is the highest number value, not ranking value.

```
optimization: {
  splitChunks: {
    cacheGroups: {
      commons: {
        test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
        name: 'vendor',
        chunks: 'all',
        priority: 1
      },
      vendor: {
        test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/](webpack|webpack-dev-server)[\\/]/,
        name: 'webpack',
        chunks: 'all',
        priority: 2
      }
    }
  },
},
```